# How would I upgrade pip in my circumstance?

Tags: python, visual-studio

Visual Studio says, `"You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 23.3.2 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command."`

The only thing that I can get pip to respond to in Terminal is `.\pip`, which displays a `Usage:` of pip commands, but none of the commands work. When trying any of them Terminal responds in red text with, `pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again...`
Below is some of the contents of a folder that VS created:

Does anyone know what my problem is?
[image: VS created folder and its contents]

Comment: from the terminal, run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Terminal's response was, "Python was not found; And I was in the Scripts folder shown above at the time.

Comment: add it to the `PATH` environment variable (I am not a Windows user), or call python with its _absolute path_

Comment: @Rand Install Python from the Microsoft Store, it'll fix the issue.

Comment: I know the folder shown above isn't in a path, but Terminal was in the Scripts folder shown above at the time I entered: "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" and the response was "Python was not found"

Comment: [How do I make Python scripts executable in Windows?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable)

Comment: Have you activated the virtual environment you seem to have set up?

Comment: esqew, how do I activate the virtual environment. Everything that has been done was done by VS, and VS also said that it was unable to upgrade pip.

Comment: SpaciousCoder78, If all else fails installing from the Microsoft store is what I'll try, My hesitaion is that I don't want python installed several times on my computer. It's a brand new computer and it looks like python is already in a few locations and that kinda bugs me.

Answer (score -1):

If there's no standalone installation of Python done on Windows (downloading the Python .msi installer and installing it), then you will get the said error, as mentioned in your question:

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again...
```

When installing the Python workload or Visual Studio, what it does it sets up the necessary Python binaries for itself to understand, but won't install it system-wide, for the command prompt to understand. You can find it out by inspecting your environment variables.

You will have to open the Visual Studio terminal, and execute the command :- `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` there itself.